# Can I Update all primary keys table using an auto_increment (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I want to change all primary keys from a table  that has a lot of rows (about 3K) using auto increment starting from 25 (for example), but only for the rows that meet one certain condition . It is possible ?. Here an example of the table:

```
create table place( 
   code int auto_increment,
   type varchar(10) not null,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   fk_place int,
   constraint pk_place primary key (code),
   constraint fk_place_place foreign key (fk_place) references place(code)
 );
```

I want to update for example, all the rows that are 'city' changing only the primary key but starting from 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a variable. Set it to one less than the value you want to start with and use an expression incrementing the variable for the right side of the `SET` of the `UPDATE`.

```
SET @i = 24;
UPDATE place
       SET code = @i := @i + 1
       WHERE <your_condition>;
```

You have to be careful though, that you don't produce dupes with the `UPDATE` or with any later `INSERT`s. Possibly use `ALTER TABLE place AUTO_INCREMENT = <new next value>;` to set the next value, which will be used for the very next `INSERT`.